# I want to host a static website on EC2 with nodejs app too

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2

I am trying to host a static website on EC2 but no luck.

here is my config file `node`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass         "http://127.0.0.1:3000";
    }
}
```

I want to host static website too.

How can I do that on EC2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how I can explain it end to end. I hope you got a basic idea of how it works.

From your question, I can understand that you are having some problems with the Nginx configuration.

your Nginx config file should look like this,

```
location / {
    # This would be the directory where your frontend code resides
    root /var/www/html/;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}

location /api {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

You can use **PM2 for running the nodejs app in your VM**.

Here Nginx would be webserver for your frontend application and a proxy to your backend application, all the request is going to hit on your Nginx server.

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: node location working but website not working I have placed all files inside specified path. Do we have to install apache ?

Comment: @MayankGupta WE don't need to install apache, nginx itself is a webserver. What kind of frontend application is this?

Comment: just some html and css pages nothing more.

Comment: @MayankGupta which one giving internal server error, if the node js then you've to check the nodejs application log

Comment: The issue was with folder permission. I have placed files in default ngnix server folder. Worked. Node app also worked at /api thanks.